# Using selenium to get access class info on website

Tags: python, selenium

I am using the following code using Python 3.6 and selenium:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("first_result_price")
print(element)
```

on the website it is like this

`website: span class="first_result_price">712

however if I print element I get a completely different number?

Any suggestions?

many thanks!!

Comment: I think we'd need to know more. One guess: at least one more element exists with that class name.

Comment: Another possibility: the web page is changing with time.

Comment: thanks guys, if I search on the website I only find the class "port" once

Comment: I just tried again and it look the same

Comment: You're not going to give us the url, are you?

Answer (score 0):

"element" is a type of object called WebElement that Selenium adds. If you want to find the *text* inside that element, you have to say

```
element.text
```

Which should return what you're looking for, '712', albeit in string form.

Comment: Many thans Menix, unfortunately if I use element.text I get "" only?

Comment: Could you provide the url to the website and the location of this HTML element? It may not actually be showing on the page, in which case you might have to reference a different property of the WebElement object.

Comment: The url is: http://www.edreams.com/?noext=1#/results/type=R;dep=2017-08-20;from=MIA;to=NYC;ret=2017-09-22;collectionmethod=false;airlinescodes=false;internalSearch=true